# How do you prevent a page break between a list and the following text?

Tags: lists, page-breaking

How do you prevent a page break between a list and the following text?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[1-3]
    \item \lipsum[5]
    \nopagebreak
\end{itemize}

\nopagebreak
\vspace{3\baselineskip}
\nopagebreak

\begin{center}
    \nopagebreak
    The end 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I would like to prevent the "The end" closing from ever appearing on a page of its own, even at the cost of breaking up the list across two separate pages.

This process needs to be automated over a number of different documents, and so, can't be adjusted manually on a case by case basis, like adding \pagebreak before the last item on the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end of a list (`itemize` and `enumerate` included), LaTeX issues a number of vertical adjustments that are not scrutinized by your `\nopagebreak` requirement. So, instead of patching `\enditemize`, include your `The end` as part of the list where you have more control over the page breaking restrictions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[1-3]
  \item \lipsum[5]
  \nopagebreak
  \vspace{3\baselineskip}
  \makeatletter
  {\centering The end\hspace*{\@totalleftmargin}\par}
  \makeatother
\end{itemize}

\begin{center}
  The end
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `center` environment itself is a list. As such, to avoid further influences that might not be captured, setting it using `{\centering ... \par}` suffices. However, sine we're in an `itemize`, some spacing corrections are required.

The final `center` environment is merely included to show the horizontal displacement is as required.